# How to groupby date in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame created from a spreadsheet and I need to split the Data Frame into multiple Dataframes based on column value. The following code works fine:

```
df = pd.read_excel("20210720.xlsx") 
# print (df)

grouped = df.groupby(df.Store) 

ninth = grouped.get_group("B")

print(ninth)
```

But when I try to group them by the Date column by doing this:

```
   df = pd.read_excel("dutchie_20210720.xlsx") 
# print (df)

grouped = df.groupby(df.Date) 

ninth = grouped.get_group("8/10/2021")

print(ninth)
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 2123, in safe_sort
    sorter = values.argsort()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Luke/Documents/Python Scripts/Menu/vlookup.py", line 11, in <module>
    ninth = grouped.get_group(8/10/2021)
  File "C:\Users\Luke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 843, in get_group
    inds = self._get_index(name)
  File "C:\Users\Luke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 672, in _get_index
    return self._get_indices([name])[0]
  File "C:\Users\Luke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 636, in _get_indices
    if len(self.indices) > 0:
  File "C:\Users\Luke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 614, in indices
    return self.grouper.indices
  File "pandas\_libs\properties.pyx", line 33, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__
  File "C:\Users\Luke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 249, in indices
    self.result_index, ABCCategoricalIndex
  File "pandas\_libs\properties.pyx", line 33, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__
  File "C:\Users\Luke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 340, in result_index
    return self.groupings[0].result_index.rename(self.names[0])
  File "pandas\_libs\properties.pyx", line 33, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__
  File "C:\Users\Luke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 600, in result_index
    return self.group_index
  File "C:\Users\Luke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 605, in group_index
    self._make_codes()
  File "C:\Users\Luke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 623, in _make_codes
    codes, uniques = algorithms.factorize(
  File "C:\Users\Luke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 727, in factorize
    uniques, codes = safe_sort(
  File "C:\Users\Luke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 2132, in safe_sort
    ordered = _sort_mixed(values)
  File "C:\Users\Luke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 2184, in _sort_mixed
    nums = np.sort(values[~str_pos])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in sort
  File "C:\Users\Luke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 996, in sort
    a.sort(axis=axis, kind=kind, order=order)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

I guess it has something to do with the fact that it's a date I just don't know how to resolve it. Can anyone offer some advice?
Here is file
[Sample file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeRad.png)

Comment: This should work if everything is getting cast to a date properly. Try adding `from datetime import datetime` and `df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x : datetime(x))`. Without the file I cant help more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that your column is using the datetime type:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Then the possible group values will be in `df['Date'].unique()`

To get an idea of your groups:

```
for group, d in df.groupy('Date'):
    print('group:', group)
    print(d)
```

or:

```
list(df.groupy('Date'))
```

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance but I just did this df = pd.read_excel("20210720.xlsx") 
# print (df)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

grouped = df.groupby(df.Date) 

ninth = grouped.get_group("8/6/2021") #also tried without quotations 

print(ninth) and got this traceback Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luke\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

Comment: Check `df['Date'].unique()`, "8/6/2021" is likely not one of your groups.

Comment: You are correct. I checked it and for some reason, it's not looking in the column named "Date" but a column with no header that contains a bunch of JSON information